# How to use form validation in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, validation, drupal

I am trying to edit the checkout form in Drupal Commerce, to require a user to enter their email address twice.  When they submit their form, Drupal should check to see if the emails match, and call `form_set_error()` if they don't.  For now, I am just trying to attach a custom validation function to the form, which I can't get to work.  (My module is called checkout_confirm_email.  This module is only for our own use, so I didn't put much effort into the name).

```
function checkout_confirm_email_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'checkout_confirm_email_form_validate';
    dprint_r($form['#validate']);
    dsm("I printed");
}
}

function checkout_confirm_email_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {    
    dsm("Never prints...");
}
```

The `dprint_r` statment outputs `Array ([0] => checkout_confirm_email_form_validate)`.  So the function is part of the form array, but the dsm statement in the validation function never prints.

I've actually been stuck for a while.  I've looked up examples, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Anyone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to attach the #validate property to the form submit button like this:

```
$form['submit']['#validate'][] = 'checkout_confirm_email_form_validate'
```

And it'll work then it's not necessary that my example is identical match to your form tree you should search for the submit button array and apply this example to it

Comment: Should this be `$form['#submit']['#validate'][]`?

Comment: No the # is for attributes not for elements

Answer (score 4):

Instead of form_set_error() I would use form_error($form, t('Error message.'));

```
function checkout_confirm_email_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'checkout_confirm_email_form_validate';
    dpm($form['#validate']);
    dsm("I printed");
  }
}

function checkout_confirm_email_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Not sure the exact email field
  if(empty($form['submitted']['mail']['#value'])){
    dsm("Should see me now and return to the form for re-submission.");
    form_error($form, t('Username or email address already in use.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is form_error better than form_set_error for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, why? Please explain!

Answer (score 4):

You could use any validate function here
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/7

The listed validations would be

- date_validate - Validates the date type to prevent invalid dates
  (e.g., February 30, 2006).
- element_validate_integer -Form element    validation handler for
  integer elements.
- element_validate_integer_positive - Form element validation handler
  for integer elements that must be positive
- element_validate_number -    Form element validation handler for
  number elements.
- password_confirm_validate - Validates a password_confirm element.

Ex of usage

```
$form['my_number_field'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Number'),
  '#default_value' => 0,
  '#size' => 20,
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_number')
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`_form_validate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/_form_validate/7).

```php
function my_form_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if ((valid_email_address($form_state['values']['field_candid_email'])) === FALSE) {
    form_set_error('field_candid_email', t('The email address is not valid.')); 
  }

  if (!(is_numeric($form_state ['values']['field_candid_montant']))) {      
    form_set_error('field_candid_montant', t('The field value must be numeric.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, do you need to set: $form['submit']['validate'][] ?

Comment: @sheldonkreger no , form_validate is a hook. what u are mentionning is defining a custom call back function to be called at form validation event

Comment: The code in this answer doesn't show how to use `_form_validate()` which should not be used by contributed modules, though.

Answer (score 2):

I changed this line:

```
$form['submit']['#validate'][] = 'checkout_confirm_email_form_validate'
```

to this:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'checkout_confirm_email_form_validate';
```

And it's works !

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
$form['submit']['#validate'][] = 'checkout_confirm_email_form_validate'
```

Comment: This has been already said from the accepted answer.